# Using て form at the end of sentences

Tags: て-form

I know that て can be used before いる, as well as when asking for ください, but I just realized I don't really know what it means. For instance, I just read an instance of て being used at the end of a sentence:"知り合いもいるからちょっと待ってて!"
What exactly does the て form mean in this context? I know it's short for いて, but even so, I've never ended a sentence with a て form verb.

Comment: Regarding 待ってて: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/948/what-does-the-final-%e3%81%a6-in-%e5%be%85%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a6%e3%81%a6-signify?rq=1 and regarding て in general: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1917/how-to-know-if-a-sentence-ending-in-the-%e3%81%a6-form-of-a-verb-is-imperative-or-not?rq=1

Answer (score 5):

In general, a standalone TE-form of a verb can be a request. You can essentially think of it as 〜ください being assumed.

In this specific case, it is 待っている that is being conjugated into TE-form, with the い getting omitted since it is casual speech:

> 知り合いもいるからちょっと待ってて
>   ＝知り合いもいるからちょっと待っていてください