# What's the いて in 「忘れないでいて」 for?

Tags: grammar

I know that the verb changes from 忘れる(to forget) to 忘れないで (don´t forget) but I can´t understand the いて at the end. 
At first, I thought it comes from the casual imperative form of いる as [this post explained](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/34332/whats-the-grammar-of-%E3%81%A6-form-%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6) but it must have a verb in a て-form before to have this "keep...ing" meaning or to make the request.

This is from a song called "Name of Love", the lyrics are as follows:

> 未来で逢えるなら
>     忘れないでいて 
>      僕のこと　本当のこと

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have found the correct question; this いて is a [subsidiary verb](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/18965/5010) that means "to be ～ing" or "to keep ～ing". What you are missing is that 忘れないで is *basically* a (negative) te-form. ないで can be followed by many subsidiary verbs including いる, おく, やる and くださる. See: [Is ないで a te-form?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11473/5010) and [ないで vs なくて: combining phrases with negative verbs](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5925/5010)

So 忘れないでいて means "(Please) don't forget me (for some time)" or "Keep remembering me."

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that! I thought the only way to negate the て-form of 忘れる was with 忘れなくて c: Thank you!

Comment: @Chrollo Actually ないで is almost always the default choice after a verb. You can say 見ないでください ("Don't look at me please") but not 見なくてください.

Comment: Understood! Thank you c: