# Te form question in bay city song

Tags: て-form

At the beginning of Junko Yagami song "Bay city" there are several te form, i can't understand how they are "resolved".

**Romaji :**
anata wo otte
Tasogare no Bay City
meguri aetara
Damatte dakitomete

**Kanji :**
あなたを追って
黄昏のBay City
めぐり逢えたら
黙って抱きとめて

**Translation i found :**
I follow you to
The Bay city in twilight
and if I see you there
Just shut up and hold me

The only verb which is not in te-form is aetara.
"au" to meet : Past Indicative of Potential Plain
this is perhaps the resolution i am searching for but 2 things bothered me :

- ra at the end of potential form
- this verb is not placed at final position

all others verbs
otte (ou)
Damatte (damaru)
dakitomete (daku)
are in te form if i am correct.

Can someone explain this or point to an article explaining this use of te form ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Which use? The last one? If you know how the て-form generally works, you should have little trouble with the first two.

Comment: If you don't know たら, [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/393/43676) might help.

Comment: And [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12026/43676) might help about the final て.

Comment: ok for the final て it must be ください being assumed.

Comment: About aetara, i can find some resources about conditional form but it should be attara. aetara form seems to refer to potential form. anyway, thanks for your links.

Comment: The potential form of a verb works as a verb in its own right.